# If clause in perl

Tags: perl

I have the following code:

```
$path = "/srv/www/root/www/data/".$img1;
my $type = `file $path`;

unless ($type =~ /JPEG/i
 || $type =~ /PNG/i) {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

I'm new to perl. I want to change this to be `if(isimagefile) perform this set of code; else perform this set of code`

What I dont understand is the logic here. I don't know what `=~` is and i dont understand the `unless` logic

**UPDATE**

Here is my current logic:

```
$path = "/srv/www/root/www/data/".$img1;
my $type = `file $path`;
if($type =~ /JPEG/i || $type =~ /PNG/i || $type=~ /JPG/i){

}
```

It doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quentin already said, `=~` is a regex test. In your case it tests whether `$type` *contains* the phrase `JPEG`. The slashes `/` are part of the syntax for regular expressions. See [Perl's tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for details.

Also, `unless` is just the opposite of `if`. Some people use it when they want to express `if (not …)`. I personally consider this bad practice because it reduces the readability, especially when the condition is made up of multiple parts and has `!`'s in it, like `unless($a>5 || ($a!=7 && (!$b)))`. It's just a horror to figure out when the condition matches.

So the code

```
unless ($type =~ /JPEG/i || $type =~ /PNG/i) {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

can be rewritten to

```
if ( ! ($type =~ /JPEG/i || $type =~ /PNG/i) ) {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
} else {
   print "The file IS a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

Or just the other way round (code blocks and condition swapped):

```
if ( $type =~ /JPEG/i || $type =~ /PNG/i ) {
   print "The file IS a valid JPEG or PNG.";
} else {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

This can further be simplified by joining the two conditions, moving them into the regular expression and ORing them there:

```
if ( $type =~ /(JPEG|PNG)/i ) {
   print "The file IS a valid JPEG or PNG.";
} else {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

The last-but-one snippet translates to *"if ($type contains JPEG) or ($type contains PNG)"* while the last one translates to *"if $type contains (JPEG or PNG)"*. The result is the same but `$type` and the regex are considered only once, which (in theory) makes it faster.

In your attempt you also refer to `JPG` (without the `E`). This can also be expressed in the regular expression, because `JPG` is just like `JPEG` but without that `E`, so the `E` is optional. Thus:

```
if ( $type =~ /(JPE?G|PNG)/i ) {
   print "The file IS a valid JPEG, JPG, or PNG.";
} else {
   print "The file is not a valid JPEG or PNG.";
}
```

The `?` denotes the optionality of the `E`. Again, see the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

`=~` tests the left hand side against [the regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) on the right hand side.

`unless (condition)` is equivalent to `if (! (condition) )`